# how to connect same mongodb (in compass using hostname: localhost and port : 27017) local in 2 different PC's

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Im trying to connect one mongodb in 2 different computer/PCs. I'm using localhost to connect the mongodb. In my 2 systems having save node, npm and mongo versions

[image]

Can anyone please help to use the same mongodb for 2 different systems. So that it is easy to use my application from any where (application developing using node.js).
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your both systems connected in one network?

Comment: What does this have to do with compass? On the "local" machine you can use "localhost". On the other machine you point to the IP address of the machine running MongoDB. Once you actually set up the server to listen on something other than the localhost interface that is. Also nothing to do with nodejs.

Comment: @NeilLunn it means i have use the ip address of the PC 1 , in the compass of PC2. 
Both machines are connecting to different networks